# Is it ok to wire load on the line side of GFCI?

Tags: electrical, gfci

I am installing a GFCI that will be feeding additional outlets in another room. There are at least 5 more outlets and I suspect this new outlet is the very first in the run. Some of these load outlets do not need to be protected, while others are *already* protected by another GFCI. In order to avoid the hassle of potential problems with daisy chaining multiple GFCIs, is it ok to simply wire the *load* onto the same terminals as the *line* on this new GFCI?

Comment: You're misusing the term "load".  "Load" does not mean "the downline".  It means "downlines you wish to extend GFCI protection to".

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely fine.

Pigtail the hot and neutral line wires to connect GFCI line, incoming wires and outgoing (not protected) wires.

Even if the  receptacle supports two wires per terminal, pigtails have some advantages:

- You get a bit more wire length to work with when installing the receptacle - limited by the pigtail rather than shortest of the two wires
- It guarantees that if you remove the GFCI, you will still have hots & neutrals paired properly. None of which should be an issue if you handle everything properly, but it just makes it simpler (at least in my mind, from a little experience and a *lot* of reading from others here).

You can also have protected receptacles on the GFCI load. But once you have both line and load, it becomes extra important to label the protected receptacles.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the advantages of pigtails in this situation?

Comment: Although I generally prefer pigtails in the case of a GFCI due to the size of the receptacle often if it can be a disadvantage to add extra wire connectors and wires

Comment: Thanks for the extra info.  In this case the box is so small that I had enough trouble jamming everything back in there without the extra real estate taken up by two more wire nuts.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease - you must have written that observation at exactly the same time as me!

Answer (score 1):

If the GFCI has provisions for multiple wires then yes, if not you may have to get some wire connectors and a couple correctly colored wires and make a pigtail connection.

Comment: Thanks - and yes, the GFCI has backwire clamps which can accommodate two wires each.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer I accepted the other only because it went into a bit more details but I wish I could accept both.